# tuple(aValidTupleOfTypeString) not returning what I expect it to

Tags: python

In the standard Python IDE:

```
>>> tuple("(5,6,7)")
('(', '5', ',', '6', ',', '7', ')')
```

is (5,6,7) a valid tuple? If so, why is tuple("(5,6,7)") placing every character in the string into its own spot in the tuple? Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: `"(5,6,7)"` is a string with `(,5,6,7,)` as its elements. So when you iterate over it, each element gets to be an element of the resulting tuple.

Answer (score 2):

[`tuple`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#tuple) accepts an iterable and creates a tuple of the values in the iterable. Example:

```
In [2]: tuple([1, 2, 42, 52, 1])
Out[2]: (1, 2, 42, 52, 1)
```

`"(5,6,7)"` is an iterable, where each element is a single character. That is why you get a tuple of single characters.

In order to create a tuple from a string, you may use [`literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) function from the `ast` module:

```
In [3]: from ast import literal_eval

In [4]: literal_eval("(5,6,7)")
Out[4]: (5, 6, 7)
```